# Returning Low Search Results using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, low-search

I am trying to pull in some Low Search results using AJAX. How can I pass a query to the result page without knowing the encrypted version of the keywords beforehand?

Here are some things I have tried.

I placed this on my result page in hopes that it would give me a URL I could use.

```
{exp:low_search:url
keywords="{segment_3}"
encode="no"
result_page="/my/result_page/"
}
```

The URL Tag spits out something like this:

```
http://mysite.com/?ACT=21&keywords=eyJjb2xsZWN0aW9uIjoiY3VzdG9tZXJfY29udHJhY3RzIiwibG9vc2VfZW5kcyI6InllcyIsInJlc3VsdF9wYWdlIjoiY29udHJhY3RzXC9zZWFyY2giLCJzZWFyY2hfbW9kZSI6ImFsbCIsImtleXdvcmRzIjoibHluIn0&result_page=%2Fmy%2Fresult_page%2F
```

I was hoping that it would not encode the keywords, and I would simply use a similar pattern for my AJAX call.

The URL it generates does not work as a stand-alone, therefor will not work for the AJAX call either. I have ruled out AJAX as being the problem, and come to the conclusion that I simply do not know how to pass keywords to Low Search without using the standard (non-js) form submit.

Any ideas?

[Link to my question with Low.](https://getsatisfaction.com/low/topics/low_search_ajax)

Comment: I have answered my own question, but can't post for another 7 hours. Once this time slot has ran it's course, I will be back with my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accepted Low's solution as correct, but I have implemented in this way:

I assumed my AJAX was good, because it worked just fine when submitting a URL that had already been encoded by Low Search. Instead of using POST method, I used GET method to send JSON `'keywords': 'my search term'`.

[Here is a piece](http://pastie.org/5558784) of the javascript puzzle stripped down for readability.

[Here](http://pastie.org/5558808) is what my result_page template looks like. Keep in mind, I am posting this answer before it is completely ready to ship. I have not included proper JSON handling if there are no results returned.

I have tried to make this a plug n' play as possible, but it certainly won't be. Actually, it's likely this isn't the best solution. I will come back if I find something I did very wrong, or if there is a simpler solution, etc.

Please feel free to tear it apart if you can offer something better :)

Answer (score 4):

The main problem here is this:

```
keywords="{segment_3}"
```

You probably don't have *keywords* in the third segment, but an entire encoded *query*. You're feeding that query as keywords to the URL tag, essentially encoding it *twice*.

If you use the URL tag and you want to work from an existing search action, use `query="{segement_3}"` to pass all the details from the existing query on to the URL. Then use any other parameters to override those.

For example, say you've searched for *foobar* using the Low Search form. That will redirect you to something like `domain.com/search/results/xxxxx`, where the segment 3 is the encoded query (*not just the keywords!*). Say you want to generate a link from that query to something else:

```
{exp:low_search:url
    query="{segment_3}"
    keywords="barfoo"
    result_page="other/template"
}
```

This will generate a URL like `domain.com/other/template/yyyyy`, using *barfoo* as keywords, but maintaining all other details given in the first query, like Collection, Search mode, etc. This link will not add the search to the log. To do that, add the `encode="no"` parameter:

```
{exp:low_search:url
    query="{segment_3}"
    keywords="barfoo"
    result_page="other/template"
    encode="no"
}
```

Which should give you something like `domain.com/?ACT=21&keywords=barfoo&result_page=other%2Ftemplate...`. This *will* add the search to the log.

Answer (score 1):

*Low really is the best person to help you troubleshoot this but I'm guessing you're in a hurry, so in the meantime...*

Could you bounce your search queries off a template containing something like the above, and then use a redirect inside that to actually return the search results to your request?

```
{redirect="{exp:low_search:url keywords="{segment_3}" result_page="/my/result_page/"}"}
```

That way you'd get a predictable URL structure to target with your ajax request, even if you can't decode the query string.

If you look at the [release notes for v2.0](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/changelog) it at least suggests that something like this should be possible, though I may well not have the syntax right:

> **2.0.0** Improved compatibility with Ajax form submissions and EE's native redirect method