# Low Search - How to use with Ajax?

Tags: low-search

I have seen [this](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/1978/returning-low-search-results-using-ajax) question about using Low Search with Ajax but I still don't see how to integrate them.

Given this form

```
{exp:low_search:form collection="foo" search_mode="any" result_page="foo/search" form_id="search_form"}
  <fieldset>
    <label for="keywords">Keywords</label>
    <input type="search" name="keywords" id="keywords" />
    <button type="submit" id="search">Search</button>
  </fieldset>
{/exp:low_search:form}
```

and this Javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search_form").on("submit", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        // HOW DO I GET THE ENCODED STRING HERE?

        var aData = [],
            sSource = $(this).attr("action");

        $.ajax(
        {
            'dataType': 'json',
            'type': 'POST',
            'url': sSource,
            'data': aData,
            'success': function (oAjaxData, sTextStatus)
            {
            },
            'error': function (jqXHR, sTextStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                console.log(sTextStatus);
            },
            'complete': function (jqXHR, sTextStatus)
            {}
        });
    });
});
```

How do I get the encoded query string in the Javascript code?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is to use the Low Search URL tag, which can produce a human-readable ACT URL with the keywords as a param.

http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/tags#url-tag

Comment: Can you show me how this would work with AJAX?

Comment: Where are you going to put this tag?

Answer (score 2):

@juddlyon is correct. I personally prefer to use the the [jQuery form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) which kind of negates the need for the url tag.

Here's the code I used:

```
{preload_replace:template_group="your-template-group"}
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$(function() {

    var $pageWrap = $('.wrap');

    var options = {
        target: $pageWrap,
        beforeSubmit:  showRequest,
        success: showResponse
    };

    // Show loading message and submit form
    function showRequest(formData, jqForm, options) {
        $pageWrap.addClass("loading").prepend('<div class="search-load">Searching</div>');
        return true;
    }

    function showResponse() {
        $pageWrap.removeClass('loading');
    }

    // bind to the form's submit event
    $('#filter').submit(function() {
        $("#filter").ajaxSubmit(options);
        return false;
    });

});
</script>

    <div class="wrap">
        {exp:low_search:form
            form_id="filter" 
            collection="insert_your_collection" 
            result_page="/{template_group}/results"
            search_mode="any"
            encode="no"
        }
            <label for="keywords">Keywords</label>
            <input type="search" name="keywords" id="keywords" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
        {/exp:low_search:form}
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think this works since you are serializing the field values. Low search doesn't use POST to get the field values. It gets them from the query string

Comment: Hey @arvinsim I'm not sure why you would think it matters if the field values are encrypted or not? The results tag on the results page will un-encrypt the query string for you automatically. If it _is_ an issue for whatever reason the url tag mentioned by juddlyon will resolve that. I can assure you the above code _does_ work, I've tested it. Where exactly are you getting stuck?

Comment: Are you saying to put it in the ajax low search results page like 
"{exp:low_search:results query="{exp:low_search:url}" group_id="7" is_member_displayable="yes"}"?

Comment: I tried using your serializeArray option and use my ajax code in the question to pass the values. The ajax call didn't return values as expected. It got redirected. I only found out later that it is because of ACT=31

Comment: Is this solution dependent on jQuery form plugin? If so, is there a solution that does not require that plugin(like what I did in my question)

Comment: Hey @arvinism, sorry I think I accidentally confused you with my crappy code example. You don't need to serialise at all. That code was redundant from something I was attempting previously. I've updated the example above which you can also find [here](http://pastie.org/5893420). I've also put together an example results page [here](http://pastie.org/5892882). This method _does_ use the jQuery Form plugin. Shouldn't be difficult to achieve without the plugin though.

Comment: Check out an unobtrusive Ajax integration method here: https://gist.github.com/4632695